# session_handler unset session Data Field still the same

Tags: php, session

I Started to same session on DB and works fine to keep an user logged in
longer then the default time from php.ini.

Two things I realized and I could not fix it yet

Garbage Collection is not working on the session_handler function

And if I use this function unset($_session["var"]) the data field still have
the name of the Session variable and same value.

**My question is:**

How Can I remove the value from the data field?

How to fix the Garbage Collection to delete the row after 30 min? (as it's not deleting)

this is my session_handler code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `session_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_data` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
)

$sdbc = NULL;

/*** Open Session ***/
function _Session_Open()
{
    global $sdbc;

    $db = 'dataBase';
    $us = 'user';
    $pw = 'password';

    // Connect to the database.
    $sdbc = mysqli_connect('host',$us, $pw, $db) or die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error());

    return true;

} // end of _Session_Open    


/*** Close Session ***/
function _Session_Close()
{
    global $sdbc;

    return mysqli_close($sdbc);

} // end of _Session_Close


/*** Read Session ***/
function _Session_Read($sid)
{
    global $sdbc;

    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

    $sid = mysqli_real_escape_string($sdbc, $sid);

    $sql = " SELECT session_data FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '$sid' ";

    $row = mysqli_query($sdbc, $sql) or die ('Line 49 ' .mysqli_error());

    // Retrieve the results:
    if (mysqli_num_rows($row) == 1) 
    {

        list($data) = mysqli_fetch_array($row, MYSQLI_NUM);

        // Return the data:
        return $data;

    } else { // Return an empty string.
        return '';
    }

    /*** clear variables ***/ 
    unset($now, $sid, $sql, $row, $data);   

} // end of _Session_Read


/*** Write Session ***/
function _Session_Write($sid, $sdata)
{
    global $sdbc;

    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sid   = mysqli_real_escape_string($sdbc, $sid);
    $sdata = mysqli_real_escape_string($sdbc, $sdata);

    $sql = " REPLACE INTO sessions 
             (session_id, last_update, session_data)
             VALUES 
             ('$sid', '$now','$sdata')
            ";

    $row = mysqli_query($sdbc, $sql) or die ('Line 86 ' .mysqli_error());

    return mysqli_affected_rows($sdbc);

    /*** clear variables ***/ 
    unset($now, $sid, $sql, $row, $data);   

} // end of _Session_Write


/*** Destroy Session ***/
function _Session_Destroy($sid)
{

    global $sdbc;

    $sql  = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '$sid'";

    $row = mysqli_query($sdbc, $sql) or die ('Line 104 ' .mysqli_error());

    return mysqli_affected_rows($sdbc);

    /*** clear variables ***/ 
    unset($sid, $sql, $row);    

} // end of _Session_Destroy



/*** Garbagge Collector ***/
function _Session_GC($maxlifetime)
{
    global $sdbc;

    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 60*270);

    $sql  = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE last_update < '$yesterday' ";

    $row = mysqli_query($sdbc, $sql) or die ('Line 124 ' .mysqli_error());

    return mysqli_affected_rows($sdbc);

    /*** clear variables ***/ 
    unset($yesterday, $sql, $row);  

} 


    /* Register the session handling functions with PHP. */
    session_set_save_handler(
                             '_Session_Open',
                             '_Session_Close',
                             '_Session_Read',
                             '_Session_Write',
                             '_Session_Destroy',
                             '_Session_GC'
                         );

    session_start();
```

Comment: Just a note: rather than 'Line 86', 'Line 104', etc., you might be interested in PHP's [`__LINE__` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Thank you Wiseguy, I did use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple calls to unset() after returning from the functions.

Samples:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($row) == 1) 
{
    list($data) = mysqli_fetch_array($row, MYSQLI_NUM);
    // Return the data:
    return $data;
} else { // Return an empty string.
    return '';
}

// WON'T REACH THIS CODE

/*** clear variables ***/ 
unset($now, $sid, $sql, $row, $data);
```

and

```
return mysqli_affected_rows($sdbc);

/*** clear variables ***/ 
unset($now, $sid, $sql, $row, $data);
```

Fix:

```
$result = ... ;
unset ( ... );
return $result;
```

Comment: I got it, Thank you Jcinacio I did fix this part.
But I still have the problem to unset session. The name and value had been not removed from data field on DB.

Comment: From the comments in session_set_save_handler [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), i believe you need to explicitly call `register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');`

Answer (score 0):

I solved one issue

I was calling session_write_close(); every time I was reading, adding or modifying values on the session variables.

so now I call session_write_close(); once on the end of my script and works perfect.

But I could not resolve the  Garbage Collection to delete the row after 30 min.